# C# INotifyPropertyChanged not working in class which overrides the Equals method?

Tags: c#

I have a `BindingList<Proxy>`, where the class Proxy implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  I also have overridden the Equals method because if I have 2 Proxy objects with the same IP and Port, I want them to be considered equal when doing comparisons.

However, if I override the Equals method, the DataGridView to which the BindingList is bound to does not update when the PropertyChanged event is raised.  If I don't override the Equals method, it works fine and as intended.

```
public class Proxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string ip;
    private int port;
    private ProxyStatus status;

    public string IP { get { return ip; } set { ip = value; OnPropertyChanged("IP"); } }
    public int Port { get { return port; } set { port = value; OnPropertyChanged("Port"} }
    public ProxyStatus Status { get { return status; } set { status = value; OnPropertyChanged("Status"); } }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Proxy(string proxy)
    {
        IP = proxy.Split(':')[0];
        Port = Convert.ToInt32(proxy.Split(':')[1]);
        Status = ProxyStatus.Unknown;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.IP + ":" + this.Port;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Proxy p = obj as Proxy;
        if (p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (p.ToString() == this.ToString())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: That GetHashCode implementation is invalid. Do this.ToString.GetHashCode... but I don't think it will fix your problem

Comment: @MineR Alright.  I guess that's not an answer to my question though because I just changed it and still having the same problem.  If I remove the Equals method theres no issue.  But I actually need to override Equals, otherwise I wouldn't be in the first place.

Comment: @JohnWick How did you solve this problem?